# Recursive Linear Search - StackOverflowError

Tags: java

I wanted to see if anyone could point me in the right direction on this, I feel like I am overlooking something very simple, the main is calling the search method on a list of about 45,000 words, which I believe is the problem, my code works for words that are in the first 6 or so thousand words in the list, but after that it encounters a StackOverflow error and crashes. I have a version of this that is non-recursive that works fine.

I have two base cases, which are the end of the array, in which case we throw ItemNotFoundException, and if the word is found, in which case we return the index at which the item was located.

My current code is:

```
public int search(String[] words, String wordToFind)
            throws ItemNotFoundException {
        return search(words, wordToFind, 0);
    }

    private int search(String[] words, String wordToFind, int index) {
        incrementCount();
        if(index == words.length) {
            // If index gets to the end of the array, then the word is not in the array
            throw new ItemNotFoundException();
        }
        if (words[index].equals(wordToFind)) {
            // If word is found, return the index.
            return index;
        } else {
            // Increment index by 1
            index++;
            // Call the search again
            return search(words, wordToFind, index);
        }
    }
```

Non-recursive code that works fine:

```
    public int search(String[] words, String wordToFind)
        throws ItemNotFoundException {
    int count = 0;
    for (String word : words) {
        incrementCount();
        if (word.equals(wordToFind)) {
            return count;
        }
        count++;
    }
    throw new ItemNotFoundException();
```

}

Comment: Why are you using recursion when a simple loop would do the job? Btw, you're _"Non-recursive code"_ is recursive since you pasted the same code two times.

Comment: Agreed. For this type of search with a large list, it's much better to use a loop to do the job instead of recursion. Use recursion only if it's more convenient. Actually all recursive algorithms can be replaced by non-recursive algorithms.

Comment: I am only trying to do this recursively because that was specified in the assignment. I fixed the code for non-recursive in the post.

Answer (score 3):

> the main is calling the search method on a list of about 45,000 words, which I believe is the problem

Yes, the huge length of the words list
is causing the stack overflow.
This is normal for so many words.

Comment: Alright, so it may just not be possible to do this because there are so many words then?

Comment: That's correct. You cannot expect a call stack with 45,000 levels of nesting to work OK.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are running into a stack overflow over and over again is that you are recursing O(n) times, where n is the size of your list.  That means that for every element in the list, you are allocating a function call to the program stack that must be preserved until you find your result.  This will naturally limit the size of a list you can search.

For larger lists, you'll want a more efficient recursive solution, like a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine! Recursively!

```
static int search(String[] words, String wordToFind, int index){
     if (index >= words.length)
         return -1;
     if (words[index] == wordToFind)
         return index;
     return search(words, wordToFind, index+1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] words = {"one", "tw0", "hello", "world"};
    String wordToFind = "hello";
    System.out.println("Index of "+ wordToFind+" in words => "+ search(words,wordToFind,0));
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.